# Getting 502, b'Bad praram in comand ->mail ERRO while sending mail using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, email, smtplib

Hi I am getting 502 error while sending a mail using python
Code :

```
import smtplib

 from email.mime.text 

import MIMEText

title = 'My title'
msg_content = '<h2>{title} > <font color="green">OK</font> </h2>\n'.format(title=title)
message = MIMEText(msg_content, 'html')

msg_full = message.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP(host='192.168.1.46',port=25)
server.set_debuglevel(True)

server.sendmail('nikhil@gmail.com',['ngaude@yahoo.com'],
            msg_full)
server.quit()




Error :
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: b'250 Welcome [192.168.62.51], Its nice to meet you\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'Welcome [192.168.62.51], Its nice to meet     you'
send: 'mail FROM:<nikhil@gmail.com>\r\n'
reply: b'502 Bad praram in comand ->mail FROM:<nikhil@gmail.com><-   \r\n'
reply: retcode (502); Msg: b'Bad praram in comand ->mail FROM:    <nikhil@gmail.com><-'
send: 'rset\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nikhil/Desktop/YYYY/ZZZ/send_email.py", line 14,   in <module>
msg_full)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 778, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (502, b'Bad praram in comand ->mail FROM:     <nikhil@gmail.com><-', 'nikhil@gmail.com')
```

Mail server is running properly.I am able to send the email using Java through the same message server.

Where am i going wrong.

Comment: Is the error message exactly "Bad praram in comand" with the spelling errors too?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the smtp server running on 192.168.1.46 . Can you reproduce the error by connecting to the smtp server with telnet `telnet 192.168.1.46 25` and typing the smtp commands directly. If so, then the problem with with the server.

Comment: @JamesK I am able to telnet on port 25.Also I am able to send the email using java client

Comment: Here is a procedure to test a server with telnet:http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/email-security-appliance/118234-technote-esa-00.html Can you test with the same commands that smtplib is sending: `ehlo [127.0.1.1]` and `mail FROM:<nikhil@gmail.com>` and then sending a test email as described. I can see nothing wrong with the python, nor with the smtp commands listed in the error message.